# Unable to add javascript function to more than one <div> container in the same class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you will see, I have a *.js*, *.aspx* and *.css* file. I have created a function in *.js* file that is going to display a bootstrap popover. However, I am not able to compile. I think there is an issue with both my function and the way I am calling it in *.aspx* view.

**HTML** (This is an aspx file using MVC)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~Scripts/bootstrap-popover.js"
<div class="bs-example tooltip-demo">
<div id = "container" class="col-md-10">
    <input id = "container" type="text" data-popover="true" data-content="Popover is working!" data-container="container" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top">
```

>

**Javascript** (This is just a custom .js file I built)

```
$('#container').popover({ 
    selector: '[data-popover]', 
    trigger: 'hover', 
    placement: 'top' });

$('container').on('hover', function() {
$({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'hover', placement: 'top' })
```

});

**CSS** (This is a custom .css file I built)

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8em 3em;
}
```

Comment: An ID of "container.data-popover" is invalid on your div. You can't have a "." in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I am still not receiving a popover on the text box.

Comment: To comment further on this....I originally had the popover feature working.  But when I tried to use the id="container" on 2 separate <div> tags in the same class, it would not compile.  So I decided to use this function so that I can call function in each separate <div> tag. If anyone has a better way of doing this, I am all ears. Note: I have also updated the code above with the changes recommended so far.

Comment: Yes, the ID must be unique on every element in the DOM. You'd be better off setting a class that just those two elements operate on, and wire up your event to the class instead of ID.

Comment: I agree. That is much easier.  The problem is that this class is part of an MVC view and I have  a variety of elements in there. That is why I thought making a function that I could just call on each <input> text box would be the best route.

Comment: Any other thoughts? @krillgar

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container').popover(..
```

This does not work because you dont have an element with id 'container'.

```
$('container').on(..
```

This does not work because you dont have an element with tag name 'container'.

**Try this**(*give your input id of "container"*):

```
 <input id = "container" type="text" data-popover="true" data-content="Popover is working!" data-container="container" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top">
```

update:
change `function PopoverTop()` to `function()`

Comment: check the update, also use chrome developer tool to debug your code and post if you are seeing any error.

Comment: I am unable to do that. I am developing this in JSFiddle environment to test how the code will run in my visual studio application since I am unable to run locally.  I did remove the name of function and I am not getting any results.  No errors, just no popover.

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with bootstrap, but it seems you are not right, refer here please . http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers